# How to set sprite's anchor point on location where mouse cursor was clicked with cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

i am trying to drag my sprite with mouse (working with Cocos2d-iphone, but on OSX system, not iOS), everything works great, but when i click on sprite and drag it, sprite goes to center of my mouse cursos, i need to change anchorpoint to mouse location, how can i do it? is there any easy way to do it with coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the anchorPoint, it just spells trouble. Changing anchorPoint is mainly useful for alignment and a few other edge cases. In all other cases use position.

In your case, simply subtract half the sprite's contentSize width & height from the position if you want to position the sprite so that its lower left corner matches the position of the cursor.

Comment: mm, i think i don't understood. I mean, when i start dragging my sprite, it centers to my mouse cursor, i don't need that, lets say my sprite is square - so when i touch upper corner (or left corner, doesn't matter) my square centers to my mouse cursor, instead of being in the same place, when it centers i can drag it without problem, it centers to my cursor, because AnchorPoint is 0.5 0.5, so i don't know how to change those things.. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you want to change anchor point? I don't think that in this case it is a good solution. You can simply take touch position changes in `ccTouchMoved:withEvent:` method and apply this position change to your sprite.

I mean if your touch moved for (5.f, 3.f) points, just add this value to sprite's previous position.